# How to play an MP3 file via JavaScript AudioWorklet?

Tags: javascript, flask, web-audio-api, audio-worklet

I've followed [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorkletNode#examples) example and created a custom AudioWorkletProcessor which works as expected. What I'd like to do now is to stream MP3 audio from my server (I'm currently using Python/Flask) into it.

So, for example

```
const response = await fetch(url);
const reader = response.body.getReader();

while (true) {
  const {value, done} = await reader.read();
  if (done) break;
  // do something with value
}
```

which gives me a `Uint8Array`. How do I pass its content to the AudioWorklet instead of the current `channel[i] = Math.random() * 2 - 1;`?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, MP3 is a compressed audio file format but the Web Audio API nodes only work with uncompressed sample data. You'll need to use the `decodeAudioData()` method of the `AudioContext` object to convert the bytes of the MP3 file into an `AudioBuffer` object.

Secondly, `decodeAudioData()` isn't really designed for streaming but because you're using MP3 you're in luck. See *[Encoding fails when I fetch audio content partially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74438153/encoding-fails-when-i-fetch-audio-content-partially)* for more information.

Thirdly, the `AudioContext` object isn't accessible from inside an `AudioWorkletProcessor`, so you'll have to call `decodeAudioData()` from the main thread and then pass the decompressed data from your `AudioWorkletNode` to your `AudioWorkletProcessor` using their respective *message ports*, which are accessible from the `port` property of each object.

Fourthly, `AudioBuffer` isn't one of the allowed types that can be sent through a message port using `postMessage()`. Fortunately the `Float32Array` returned by the buffer's `getChannelData()` method is one of the supported types.

I'm not sure what your reason is for using an audio worklet. Depends on what you want to do with the MP3 but if all you want to do is play it then there are simpler solutions that involve lower CPU usage.

Answer (score 2):

My approach to streaming audio would be to start with an `<audio>` tag or `Audio` object (same thing). That way the browser would handle all the streaming and decoding issues for me without further intervention. Then if I wanted to transfer the audio into the Web Audio API to do some client side real-time post processing then I'd use a `MediaElementAudioSourceNode` to achieve that. Then I'd use the built-in audio node types like `BiquadFilterNode` for EQ, `DynamicsCompressorNode` for dynamic range compression, and `ConvolverNode` for reverb. Only if I needed to do something that it wasn't possible to construct using the built-in node types no matter what combination they were assembled in, only then would I start writing an audio worklet. And unfortunately there are a few common things that the built-in Web Audio nodes cannot do. A single pole filter with a variable cutoff is one example (though if a fixed cutoff is acceptable then an `IIRFilterNode` can be used). Sample and hold is another. Being able to work around these kinds of limitations is why audio worklets rock and are super useful as small components within a larger system of nodes.

A second thing I wanted to clarify with respect to my previous answer is that although my suggestion isn't wrong *per se* (that is how you'd get any kind data into an `AudioWorkletProcessor` that isn't an *input* or an `AudioParam`, for example to emulate something similar to the `buffer` property on the `ConvolverNode`), your approach using `fetch()` and the phrase, "Pass its content to the AudioWorklet" (i.e. the `Uint8Array`) led me down a dubious line of thinking. What you have is a *stream* of data. The fact that the server sends it as MP3 is irrelevant. The Web Audio API works using a streams paradigm too. The more common ways to get data into an audio worklet are either:

1. To give the worklet an *input*. Then you can pass an instance of the worklet as a parameter to another node's `connect()` method, or,
2. By giving the worklet an `AudioParam`.

Which one is appropriate depends on what you will be doing with the content of the MP3 but if you don't already have another input defined then it's probably an input. To get the stream of MP3 data into the format the Web Audio API uses for its streams you need a `MediaElementAudioSourceNode` (or an `AudioBufferSourceNode` for a non-streaming MP3 file). Then connect the `MediaElementAudioSourceNode` into your worklet using `connect()`. Inputs are all interchangeable so if implemented this way then your worklet would be able to process any kind of audio data connected into it and wouldn't be limited to only processing MP3. When you're writing worklet code you usually don't care about where the audio is coming from. All inputs and `AudioParams` are just streams of samples (without compression).

This [Chrome Developers blog post](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/audio-worklet) covers how to make worklets that have their own inputs and `AudioParam`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (let i=0; i < value.length; i++) {
    channel[i] = value[i];
}
```

Comment: Please, elaborate a bit. Code only answers are not advisable, and get automatically flagged as "low quality" by the deletion vote system.