# Encoding fails when I fetch audio content partially

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, web-audio-api

I use the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to make API call and receive audio files partially (206).
When I try to convert the result into `AudioBuffer` and consume it with [audio-play](https://www.npmjs.com/package/audio-play) I get the following error:

> DOMException: The buffer passed to decodeAudioData contains invalid content which cannot be decoded successfully.

Here is the simplified code base:

```
const context = new AudioContext();

fetch(
  'API/ENDPOINT',
  {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
      'range': `bytes=${range[0]}-${range[1]}`,
    },
  }
)
.then((partialContent) => partialContent.arrayBuffer())
.then((arrayBuffer) => context.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer))
.then((audioBuffer) => {
  console.log('@todo: Use the buffer to play the sound');
})
.catch(console.log);
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `decodeAudioData()` can only decode full files. But it looks like you're using MP3s. If you cut them exactly at the frame boundary you can make `decodeAudioData()` believe that it deals with full files. [Rich-Harris/phonograph](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/phonograph) is for example a project which does this.

The more modern way of solving this would be to use [WebCodecs](https://w3c.github.io/webcodecs/) which allows you to decode the audio in chunks.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense. I was sending back 100KB chunks. I was wondering about such issue myself, but I didn't know how to fix it.